# Show employee with highest number of sales

Tags: sql

I would like to show the employee with the highest number of sales

i used a subquery to count every employee's sales, and showed the top one, then used that to show that employee's information

```
SELECT
TOP 1 staff_id, 
COUNT(*) 
AS sales
FROM orders
GROUP BY staff_id 
ORDER BY sales DESC
```

it shows that the employee with the ID=6 has the highest number of sales
but when passing this as a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM staffs 
WHERE (staff_id =
            
((select top 1 staff_id, count(*) as sales from orders group by staff_id order by sales desc )))
```

i get the follwing error:
**only one expression can be specified in the select when the subquery is not introduced with exists
**

Comment: The error message really is very clear, your sub query is returning `staff_id` and `count(*)` - which of those two values should be equated in the expression? The query optimizer has no idea and it's telling you so.

Comment: it should compare it to staff_id, how do i tell it to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query instead.

This returns a single expression, which the error is telling you is expected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM staffs 
WHERE staff_id in (
  SELECT TOP (1) staff_id
  FROM orders 
  GROUP BY staff_id
  ORDER BY count(*) DESC
);
```

You might also want to look at the `with_ties` clause to handle where there are duplicate counts.